# adding 2 selectList aspMvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dropdown, selectlist

I've got two `ViewBag` there and I would like to make one 
in that way I can get the 2 different address of the customer shown in one `DropDownList`

```
....
var customerAdress = from cl2 in dc.Adresses
                   where cl2.Customer.User.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name
                   select cl2;

var Adresses = new SelectList(customerAdress.ToList(), "AdressID", "AdressLine1 ", null);
var Adresses2 = new SelectList(customerAdress.ToList(), "AdressID", "AdressLine2", null);
....
```

there is my View:

```
....
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        @Html.DropDownList("Adresses", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(ViewBag.Adresses))

    </td>
</tr>
.....
```

Comment: can you give example what should be expected result?

Comment: instead of displaying in multiple dropdown, you can show both data inside a single dropdown separated with group like Bootstrap Multiselect. refer https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Answer (score 2):

You would need to concatenate them to be shown in one dropdown list like:

```
var addressesList = customerAdress
                    Select(x=> new 
                           { 
                             ID = x.AddressID,
                             AddressLine = x.AddressLine1 + x.AddressLine2
                           });

ViewBag.Adresses = new SelectList(addressesList.ToList() , "AdressID", "AddressLine ", null);
```

and do not set the `DropDownList` helper name same as your `ViewBag` key, they should be different to prevent unexpected behaviors.

And in view do like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectAddress",ViewBag.Adresses as SelectList,"Select Address")
```

When you set the name of the DropDownList helper to be the same as ViewBag key it will look for a key in the ViewBag for populating the DropDownList items, in that case you would need to just specify name to be same as `ViewBag` key:

```
Html.DropDownList("Adresses","Select Address")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectAddress'.

Comment: and i don't want concatenate them no way i would like them to be displayed as item of a dropdown list

Comment: AddressLine = x.AddressLine1 + x.AddressLine2

Comment: corrected @bob and you would need to concatenate, there is no other way, if you wan to show both addresses in the select option

Answer (score 0):

my question wasn't clear it contained already a try of solution which may have mislead all the solution i've got
so here my solution i just used  Group property on SelectListItem

my controller

```
....

    var customerAdress = from cl2 in dc.Adresses
                                     where cl2.Customer.User.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name
                                     where cl2.Commands.FirstOrDefault().DeliveryAdressID==cl2.AdressID
                                     select cl2;

                var addressesList = customerAdress.
                        Select(x => new
                        {
                            ID = x.AdressID,
                            AddressLine = x.AdressLine1


                        });
                var addressesList2 = customerAdress.
                    Select (x => new
                    {
                        ID = x.AdressID,
                        AddressLine = x.AdressLine2


                    }) ;
                var allAdress = new List<SelectListItem>();

                var group1 = new SelectListGroup() { Name = "DeliverableAdress" };

                foreach (var item in addressesList)
                {
                    allAdress.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.AddressLine, Group = group1 });

                }
                foreach (var item in addressesList2)
                {

                    allAdress.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.AddressLine, Group = group1 });
                }

                //var Adresses = new SelectList(addressesList.ToList(), "AdressID", "AddressLine ", null);
                ViewBag.allAdress = allAdress;
  ....
```

and my view

```
....
<tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            @Html.DropDownList("allAdress", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.allAdress)



                        </td>
                    </tr>
....
```

but actually i misunderstood it the right idea is t concatenate the 2 adresslines because it's just details of one address and no 2 address as i thought